# Is it possible to change the /resources folder name which is used by h:outputStylesheet and h:outputScript

Tags: javascript, css, jsf-2, resources, location

Is it necessary to give the folder name "resources" when making the reference of a css file and js file in `h:outputStylesheet` and `h:outputScript`?

Cause when I am giving the folder name "assets" instead of "resources" these files are not loaded.

This is how I am using these tags:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css"/>
    <h:outputScript name="js/site.js"/>
</h:head>
```

And here is my project structure:

[image]

In the screenshot you can see the folder name is resources. And then it is working. How can I specify a different name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The folder name is fixed as per chapters 2.6.1.1 and 2.6.1.2 of the [JSF specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html).

> #### 2.6.1.1 Packaging Resources into the Web Application Root
>
> The default implementation must support packaging resources in the web application root
>   under the path
>
> ```
> resources/<resourceIdentifier>
> ```
>
> relative to the web app root. Resources packaged into the web app root must be accessed using the `getResource*()` methods on ExternalContext.
>
> #### 2.6.1.2 Packaging Resources into the Classpath
>
> For the default implementation, resources packaged in the classpath must reside under the
>   JAR entry name:
>
> ```
> META-INF/resources/<resourceIdentifier>
> ```
>
> Resources packaged into the classpath must be accessed using the `getResource*()` methods of the `ClassLoader` obtained by calling the `getContextClassLoader()` method of the current `Thread`.

It mentions "must" in both cases. It does not mention anything about a possible configuration option to change those paths. This applies to both JSF 2.0 and JSF 2.1.

In the upcoming JSF 2.2, however, it will as per [JSF spec issue 996](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-996) be possible to change the path by the new `javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY` context parameter which takes a path relative to the webcontent root as parameter value:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/resources</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

This example will move the `/resources` folder into `/WEB-INF`, hereby ensuring more security (i.e. it is now not possible anymore to access those resources independently from the `FacesServlet`).

In *your particular case*, you'd thus like to use the following setting when having upgraded to JSF 2.2:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>assets</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Note that this only covers webapp's own resources as specified in chapter 2.6.1.1, not the JAR resources as specified in chapter 2.6.1.2. The path of JAR resources should still be `META-INF/resources` as this is controlled by Servlet API specification, not the JSF specification. It's namely under the covers obtained by [`ServletContext#getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method which is outside control of JSF.

Comment: Just to add, I am using Mojarra 2.2.1 with Spring webflow 2.4.0.M1 and the param-value must start with a forward slash for this to work. So /WEB-INF/resources. I am guessing this is an issue with Webflow.

Comment: @annihilate: this is an issue in javadoc. According the source code it must indeed start with `/`. See also last comment of https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-996

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify another directory than *resources* unless yiu are using

```
<style></style>
```

or

[OmniFaces CombinedResourceHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler)

Comment: thanks. can you please explain why do we need it to be resources?

Answer (score 1):

It is the way that the Resource Handler has been implemented in JSF 2.0, by default it will look at the following two path:

1) /resources under the root of the web application.

2) /META-INF/resources when packaged in an external JAR on the classpath.

If you want to use a different name, As mentioned by Alexandre, use the `<script>` and `<style>` tags or write your own Resource Handler.

More info:

- [Ryan Lubke's blog entry on JSF 2.0 Resource API](https://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/jsf_2_0_new_feature5)
- [JSF 2.0 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)