# JSF resources render RES_NOT_FOUND URLs

Tags: jsf, resources, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with resources on my JSF page. Everything seems to be ok and IDE finds my files in xhtml, but when page is loaded I get `RES_NOT_FOUND` error instead of actual resources.

This is source document:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css"/>
    <h:outputScript name="js/jquery-2.2.0.js"/>
</h:head>
```

And this is output document:

```
<head id="j_idt2">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="RES_NOT_FOUND"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />
</head>
```

This is my directory tree:

[image: directories]

Comment: How did you get an upvote in 1 minute on a question like this?

Comment: Project structure looks OK. Problem suggests build or deploy failed. Let your build system produce/export a WAR file. Extract it with a ZIP tool and inspect if the resources are in the right place. This way you can exclude if it's fault of build or deploy.

Answer (score -1):

Put this in the web.xml file, The following fragment of code below specifies the directory used for resource lookup in the file system of the web application.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
</context-param>
```

All the resource files go under this directory (img, js, etc). Like this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671704/is-it-possible-to-change-the-resources-folder-name-which-is-used-by-houtputsty)